# Laggy animation when enemy gets within certain distance of player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I have created some code for my unity game. When my player reaches a certain distance to my enemy the enemy goes from idle to run and then when it gets within a closer distance it switches to the attack animation. When it goes from idle to run the animation looks really weird and the enemy floats along the ground and and then plays the run animation.

Can anyone see why?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour  {

    CharacterController _controller;
    Transform _player;

    [SerializeField]
    float _moveSpeed = 5.0f;

    [SerializeField]
    float _gravity = 2.0f;

    float _yvelocity = 0.0f;
    // max distance enemy can be before he moves towards you    
    float maxDistance = 15.0f;

    float attackDistance = 5.0f;

    Animation _animation;

    void Start()
    {
        _animation = GetComponentInChildren<Animation>(); 

        GameObject playerGameObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        _player = playerGameObject.transform;
        _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        _animation.CrossFade("idle1_"); 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 direction = _player.position - transform.position;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

        Vector3 velocity = direction * _moveSpeed;

        if (!_controller.isGrounded)
        {
            _yvelocity -= _gravity;
        }

        velocity.y = _yvelocity;

        direction.y =0;

        if (Vector3.Distance(_player.position, transform.position) < maxDistance) {
            _controller.Move(velocity*Time.deltaTime);
            _animation.CrossFade("run_");
        }

        if (Vector3.Distance(_player.position, transform.position) < maxDistance && (Vector3.Distance(_player.position, transform.position) < attackDistance)) {
            _animation.CrossFade("hornAttack1_", 0.5f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe that's happening because you are calling `_animation.CrossFade("run_");` and `_animation.CrossFade("hornAttack1_", 0.5f);` multiple times, inside the Update method. Once the Enemy get close to the player the CrossFade will be called once per frame.
Try to implement some kind of block like the pseudo-code bellow:

```
bool _enemyIsOnAttackArea = false;
if(!_enemyIsOnAttackArea){
   _enemyIsOnAttackArea = true;
   // Do your stuff
   _animation.CrossFade("run_");
}
```

*When the enemy is out of range, you remove the block.

EDIT:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour  {

    CharacterController _controller;
    Transform _player;

    [SerializeField]
    float _moveSpeed = 5.0f;

    [SerializeField]
    float _gravity = 2.0f;

    float _yvelocity = 0.0f;
    // max distance enemy can be before he moves towards you    
    float maxDistance = 15.0f;

    float attackDistance = 5.0f;

    Animation _animation;

    /// <summary>
    /// The _enemy is in run range.
    /// </summary>
    bool _enemyIsInRunRange = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// The _enemy is in attack range.
    /// </summary>
    bool _enemyIsInAttackRange = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// "Run Range" block flag. 
    /// </summary>
    bool _enemyIsInRunRangeBlock = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// "Attack Range" block flag.
    /// </summary>
    bool _enemyIsInAttackRangeBlock = false;


    void Start()
    {
        _animation = GetComponentInChildren<Animation>(); 

        GameObject playerGameObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        _player = playerGameObject.transform;
        _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        _animation.CrossFade("idle1_"); 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 direction = _player.position - transform.position;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

        Vector3 velocity = direction * _moveSpeed;

        if (!_controller.isGrounded)
        {
            _yvelocity -= _gravity;
        }

        velocity.y = _yvelocity;

        direction.y =0;


        // Setted two bools here with your distance calculations
        _enemyIsInRunRange = Vector3.Distance(_player.position, transform.position) < maxDistance;
        _enemyIsInAttackRange = Vector3.Distance(_player.position, transform.position) < attackDistance;

        // If enemy is in "Run" range
        if (_enemyIsInRunRange) {

            // Do other stuff when the enemy is inside the "Run" range (Remember that here is one call per frame, that's why we made the block flags)

            _controller.Move(velocity*Time.deltaTime);

            // Check if there's a flag to block, if not we call the CrossFade and raise the Run Block flag up
            if(!_enemyIsInRunRangeBlock){
                _animation.CrossFade("run_");
                // Raising the block so this will be called only once until the enemy goes out of the "Run" range
                _enemyIsInRunRangeBlock = true;
            }
        }
        // if not in "Run" range, we drop the flag
        else
        {
            _enemyIsInRunRangeBlock = false;
        }

        // if the enemy is in the Attack Range
        if (_enemyIsInAttackRange) {

            // Do other stuff when the enemy is inside the "Attack" range (Remember that here is one call per frame)

            // Check if theres a "Attack Block" flag down and call the CrossFade
            if(!_enemyIsInAttackRangeBlock){
                // Calling Cross Fade only once
                _animation.CrossFade("hornAttack1_", 0.5f);
                // Raising the block so this will be called only once until the enemy goes out of the "Attack" range
                _enemyIsInAttackRangeBlock = true;
            }
        }
        // If enemy is out of range for a Attack we drop the flag
        else
        {
            _enemyIsInAttackRangeBlock = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I have to make a function for that? like public void attack or something?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a complete code for you but I was not able to test it so test it and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Just tried, it's still realy jolty and now if i run away they seem to float in the air

Comment: Do you have a Rigidbody attached to the enemy GO?

Comment: No I don't, i have a ragdoll

Comment: I used the code on a different character i had and it worked. Must of been the character i was using. Thank you!

Comment: I was going to ask you that because I was able to test the code in my answer here and it worked OK but it was without the animations and using a primitive. Sorry I couldn't help you more.

Comment: How would i get it to go back to idle when i run away and get out of both the ranges? At the moment it keeps on playing the attack animation